# Cannot access dynamically created span using GetElementsByName?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, getelementsbyname

I have a situation dealing with some legacy code, and it seems what used to work isn't working any longer.  I have two code block fragments, that by all appearances should be identical in functioning, but the first one can be found using getElementsByName:

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = '<span id="mySpan" name="mySpan">My New Span</span>';
    row.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

This second one cannot be found using getElementsByName:

```
function myOtherFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.id = 'mySpan2';
    span.name = 'mySpan2';
    span.innerHTML = 'My New Span';
    td.appendChild(span);
    row.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

If I then run the following code,

```
function findIt() {
    var mySpan = document.getElementsByName('mySpan')[0];
    var mySpan2 = document.getElementsByName('mySpan2')[0];
}
```

then mySpan will point correctly to the element I need to access, but mySpan2 won't.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling those functions?

Comment: ibrahim and Derek, you are correct, that this is a duplicate answer, but I had no clue that the .name no longer worked, and that I would need .setAttribute() to make it work!  Thanks so much!!!